# SolrCloud update node by node after schema update

Tags: indexing, solr, replication

Is it possible to update one node by one in SOLRCluster so you after update of SOLR schema you will not have to reindex all nodes at once and have downtime of search?

[Current SolrCluster configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bRpGt.jpg)

So basically can I:

1. Put one node into recovering mode
2. Update this node

   - Update schema.xml
   - Reindex Node
3. Bring this node as Leader
4. Put another node into recovery mode
5. Update this node too and launch it

Or I didn't get something?

Comment: what do you mean with "update this node"? You can use an Alias for a list of collection so you can reindex one collection after each other.

Comment: But can I update only 1 node in collection and then make replica of it to another one?

Comment: what do you mean with "update a node"?

Comment: update scheme for one node

Comment: what do you mean with "scheme"? Do you mean "schema.xml" from conf-folder? Please give the point "2. Update this node" some sub-points.

Comment: Yes, I mean schema.xml. But now I understand that this is imposible due to 2 nodes are replicated, so they both should have the same index and the same schema.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is how to update the schema.xml in SolrCloud.

This answer is about changes in schema.xml which does not imply the nead of a reindexing.

I also assume that you have [create](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Collections+API#CollectionsAPI-api1) your collection with an named configuration in zookeeper(collection.configName).

In this case:

1. [Upload](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Using+ZooKeeper+to+Manage+Configuration+Files#UsingZooKeepertoManageConfigurationFiles-UploadingconfigsusingzkcliorSolrJ) your changed configuration folder to zookeeper.
2. [Reload](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Collections+API#CollectionsAPI-api2) your collection

Be aware that step 2. need the name of the collection (does not support alias).